# mysql DB Import script issue on version 5.6

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a production server that hosts mysql 5.0 database. From there I exported the db backup script using export feature provided in phpmyadmin.

Now I want to restore database script on new server that 5.6 mysql. But when I run the import script I get following error:

```
Error Description:
unexpected character. (near at position mysql
```

On further investigation I found that the query was getting break at following location, please see image given below:
[image]

I noticed that this scring variable has **102129 Characters** I also verified that I put '' in starting or in between then it does not break, but after n character it breaks & quite visible in phpmyadmin editor.

I am aware of using \' escape specifier, but this option is not useful in my case as this script is really long I manually can't replace such occurrances.

Please suggest any really healping solution.

**Info:**
*While I was writing this post, I tried to execute the DB Script for single Record only (i.e., removing all other script) then i executed successfully. Therefore I can't identify the real reason for this issue.*

**Please suggest any db migration technique that I can use in this scenario.**

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Following is the query that is being throwing exception on production phpmyadmin, but working elsewhere:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_id`, `option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`, `blog_id`) VALUES
(297, 'wpcs_options', 'a:40:{s:5:"width";s:3:"973";s:6:"height";s:3:"399";s:12:"border_width";s:1:"0";s:12:"border_color";s:7:"#ffffff";s:11:"font_family";s:39:"\\''Trebuchet MS\\'', Helvetica, sans-serif";s:9:"font_size";s:2:"12";s:5:"color";s:7:"#000000";s:12:"heading_font";s:2:"18";s:13:"heading_color";s:7:"#ffffff";s:16:"background_color";s:7:"#ffffff";s:6:"update";s:7:"UPDATED";s:16:"square_per_width";s:1:"7";s:17:"square_per_height";s:1:"5";s:5:"delay";s:4:"3000";s:6:"sDelay";s:2:"30";s:7:"opacity";s:3:"0.7";s:10:"titleSpeed";s:3:"500";s:6:"effect";s:6:"random";s:10:"hoverPause";s:4:"true";s:24:"navigation_next_previous";s:4:"true";s:18:"navigation_buttons";s:4:"true";s:16:"navigation_color";s:7:"#000000";s:12:"show_excerpt";s:5:"false";s:11:"char_length";s:3:"200";s:10:"new_window";s:5:"false";s:5:"order";s:5:"false";s:12:"custom_image";s:4:"true";s:13:"post_category";s:1:"0";s:15:"number_of_posts";s:1:"4";s:19:"no_of_custom_images";s:1:"5";s:12:"slide_image1";s:92:"http://mydemozone.com/signaturewellnessv2/wp-content/plugins/content-slide/images/image1.jpg";s:16:"slide_imagelink1";s:60:"http://www.snilesh.com/resources/jquery/jquery-image-slider/";s:12:"slide_image2";s:92:"http://mydemozone.com/signaturewellnessv2/wp-content/plugins/content-slide/images/image2.jpg";s:16:"slide_imagelink2";s:132:"http://www.snilesh.com/resources/wordpress/wordpress-tips-and-tricks/wordpress-show-title-and-excerpt-of-child-pages-on-parent-page/";s:12:"slide_image3";s:92:"http://mydemozone.com/signaturewellnessv2/wp-content/plugins/content-slide/images/image3.jpg";s:16:"slide_imagelink3";s:90:"http://www.snilesh.com/resources/wordpress/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-news-ticker-plugin/";s:12:"slide_image4";s:92:"http://mydemozone.com/signaturewellnessv2/wp-content/plugins/content-slide/images/image4.jpg";s:16:"slide_imagelink4";s:66:"http://www.snilesh.com/resources/jquery/jquery-image-sliders-2010/";s:12:"slide_image5";s:92:"http://mydemozone.com/signaturewellnessv2/wp-content/plugins/content-slide/images/image5.jpg";s:16:"slide_imagelink5";s:65:"http://www.snilesh.com/resources/jquery/jquery-dynamic-selectbox/";}', 'yes', 0);
```

The above query returns following error:

```
Error
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Ending quote ' was expected. (near "" at position 349)
SQL query:

INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_id`, `option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`, `blog_id`) VALUES (297, 'wpcs_options', 'a:40:{s:5:"width";s:3:"973";s:6:"height";s:3:"399";s:12:"border_width";s:1:"0";s:12:"border_color";s:7:"#ffffff";s:11:"font_family";s:39:"\\''Trebuchet MS\\'', Helvetica, sans-serif";s:9:"font_size";s:2:"12";s:5:"color";s:7:"

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''a:40:{s:5:"width";s:3:"973";s:6:"height";s:3:"399";s:12:"border_width";s:1:"0";' at line 2
```

Comment: any help. what should i be checking in server? any php.ini variables?

Comment: max query length or something else? Actually it was wordpress 3.3 installed on network solutions shared server and mysql is 5.0 But now mysql database is of 5.6. When i am exporting wordpress and then re-importing the same, it gives this error. can i check some option while exporting and some option while importing because of which this error will not come.